# Is the regular representation of a fusion ring a direct sum of all its irreducible representations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, fusion-categories

For groups, the regular representation contains each irrep with multiplicity equal to the irrep's dimension.

For (not necessarily commutative) fusion rings, is there any analogous statement for the regular representation (= fusion matrix)?